# How to reference a local variable by its declared name

Tags: java, swing

if I have a button click handler function, I want to be able to identify which button was clicked by its reference name (e.g minimize_button or maximize_button) and **NOT** by using:

```
minimize_button.setName("minimize_button");
```

```
class Game extends JFrame
{
    public Game()
    {
        JButton minimize_button = new JButton();

        minimize_button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
             public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouse)
             {
                 setWindowState(mouse); 
             }
        });

        JButton maximize_button = new JButton();

        maximize_button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
             public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouse)
             {
                 setWindowState(mouse); 
             }
        });
    }

    private void setWindowState(MouseEvent mouse)
    {
        int window_state = Game.this.getExtendedState();

        JButton button = (JButton)mouse.getComponent();

        if (button == minimize_button)
        {
            if (window_state == JFrame.NORMAL || window_state == JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)
                window_state = JFrame.ICONIFIED;
        }
        else if (button == maximize_button)
        {
            if (window_state == JFrame.NORMAL)
                window_state = JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;
            else if (window_state == JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)
                window_state = JFrame.NORMAL;
        }

        Game.this.setExtendedState(window_state);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** i do NOT want to declare it as a class variable
**EDIT:** the reason why i need to process button clicks in one function is because i don't want to duplicate code (see below).  i don't want the following:

```
class Game extends JFrame
{
    public Game()
    {
        JButton minimize_button = new JButton();

        minimize_button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
             public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouse)
             {
                 int window_state = Game.this.getExtendedState();

                 if (window_state == JFrame.NORMAL || window_state == JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)
                    Game.this.setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
             }
        });

        JButton maximize_button = new JButton();

        maximize_button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
             public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouse)
             {
                 int window_state = Game.this.getExtendedState();

                 if (window_state == JFrame.NORMAL)
                     window_state = JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;
                 else if (window_state == JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)
                     window_state = JFrame.NORMAL;

                 Game.this.setExtendedState(window_state);
             }
        });
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** kindly refrain from commenting "oh, you should do it this way".  all i want to know is, can i reference a variable by its reference name. if so, how?  reflection in the above example will not work, as i've stated, i do not want to declare them as class variables.

Comment: Did you look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html?

Comment: (1-) What duplicate code? The only duplicate code I see is the getting/setting of the extended state. There is no reason to do what you are doing. You really are complicating the whole process.The minimize and maximize listener both contain different functionality and should not be combined into a single listener. You should not even be using a MouseListener on the JButton. You should be using an `ActionListener`.

Comment: @camickr, you are correct, only one setting is modified.  however, as i've pointed out, the above is only an example.  ill be making several changes whenever the window state is changed.   regarding "You should be using...." please read bottom NOTE.

Comment: @johnny, That bottom notes means nothing. If you ask a question the question should make sense and the posted code should also make sense so we can better understand what you are asking. Attempting to use a MouseListener to listen for a click of the button would indicate you are not familiar with Swing. Not being familiar with Swing can also indicate you may be making other bad design decisions, such as what you are attempting to do here. There are better solutions.

Comment: For example maybe you can create a custom `ActionListener` that takes a `boolean` parameter (lets call it)  `isMaximize`. Then you create two `ActionListeners`, one for each button with true/false values. Then the logic internally is based on the boolean value and the reference name is irrelevant. You should not be coding based on reference names. So you SHOULD be asking for the better way to solve the problem

Comment: @camickr, i'll give it one more go.  whether its good practice or not, can a component that's not a class field be referenced by its reference name?

Comment: Yes, the anonymous listener can reference the button by its reference name. No, a method can't reference the button by its reference name. You need to spend more time learning about how to create reusable code, instead of trying to find hacks to a poor design. In you first example there is no need to two listener. Just create one listener and add the same listener to each button.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you're trying to access minimize_button and maximize_button outside their scope. They cease to "exist" outside of the Game() constructor you have declared them in. Nothing can be done to change this.

An alternative would have been to declare them as class variables, aka attributes. You have stated you do not want this.

The most minimal change I can propose to get this to compile is the following. I wouldn't recommend this, but it answers your question within the constraints you've identified. Here I've passed minimize and maximize button references into your "shared" method setWindowState().

```
public Game() {
    JButton minimize_button = new JButton();
    JButton maximize_button = new JButton();

    minimize_button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouse) {
            setWindowState(mouse, minimize_button, maximize_button);
        }
    });

    maximize_button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouse) {
            setWindowState(mouse, minimize_button, maximize_button);
        }
    });
}

private void setWindowState(MouseEvent mouse, JComponent minimize_button, JComponent maximize_button) {
    int window_state = Game.this.getExtendedState();
    JButton button = (JButton) mouse.getComponent();

    if (button == minimize_button) {
        if (window_state == JFrame.NORMAL || window_state == JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)
            window_state = JFrame.ICONIFIED;
    } else if (button == maximize_button) {
        if (window_state == JFrame.NORMAL) {
            window_state = JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;
        } else if (window_state == JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) {
            window_state = JFrame.NORMAL;
        }
    }
    Game.this.setExtendedState(window_state);
}
```

Comment: as i've clearly stated, i do not want to reference an object by name.  all i want to know is can i reference a variable by its reference name.  my code is only an example to illustrate what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @johnny Apologies, I was merely trying to guide you in writing more robust, maintainable code. I've updated my answer. In short what you're after is simply not possible.

Comment: "@adam", no apology required.  i suspected it wasn't possible. i guess Object.setName(String) will have to do.